# In Firestore how to retrieve the document ID in a foreach enumeration

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

in my web app I query a Firestore database to enum orders.
This is working but I need to access to the ID of each order.

```
// Get Data
var resRef = firebase.firestore().collection("orders");
resRef.get().then( (orderList) => {

    orderList.forEach(
        function(order){
            console.log("order ID: ", order.?? )
            ...
        }
    )
    ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of each document is available as `order.id`. So:

```
var resRef = firebase.firestore().collection("orders");
resRef.get().then( (orderList) => {

    orderList.forEach(
        function(order){
            console.log("order ID: ", order.id )
            ...
        }
    )
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web_4).